Как выровнять кнопки в ячейках таблицы по центру? css Без изменения границ
Показываю кусок таблицы

Кнопки не выровнены. Не помогает
td:last-child{display: inline-block; text-align: center;}

Я добавил:
td:last-child{display:flex; justify-content:center; height:100%;}


Ячейки из-за своих границы выгдяят отчуждёнными. Казалось бы, на это можно не обращать внимание. Но при сужении страницы ячейка остаётся в прежних размерах, когда остальные ячейки расширяются вдоль.

При
flex-direction: column;

Кнопки в ячейке становятся в столбик, даже без сужения.

К кнопкам добавлен
vertical-align: top;

